# Can I nominate someone for an award for answering an extremely tough question?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way of asking for someone to receive a medal or badge such as "badge for answering an extremely tough question that many other people struggled to answer?"

In this particular case I am thinking specifically of [Can Eight Retrograde (seen from Earth) planets occur?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32426/7982) but my question here applies generally.

Comment: That was a particularly cool question, and it's great that @barrycarter took the time to dig in and find some solutions! I've stopped by to up vote that answer, I hadn't seen it until you mentioned it here. Unfortunately things like nominating specific people for specific things doesn't really happen in Stack Exchange (except for moderator elections). Early on there was a lot of gaming the system activities, users working together to up each others' reputation (points) so now it's pretty much just the community's up voting.

Comment: As pointed out in the other answer, there is the bounty system but it's zero-sun-gain, you have to lose for someone else to gain. Even that system was gamed in the beginning and had to be modified accordingly, see answers to: [Any way to award a second +100 bounty to a second answer to the same question?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863/12102) as well as [Will/would it be impossible for me to add a third bounty here? Why was 500 my only choice for #2?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/888/12102).

Comment: Also see [How does the bounty auto-award work?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/12102) and also [Is there any utility for a 24 hour grace period on bounties on questions with no answers?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/877/12102) for further details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I get what you mean; I, too, have gotten some amazing answers across Stack Exchange that made me think "Wow, where did *that* come from?" While you can't award someone a *badge* for top-notch work, you *can* [offer a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/274942) on the question (assuming it's at least two days old) of anywhere from 50 to 500 reputation points, and award it to their answer. Now, that does require you to have enough reputation points to give away, and right now you only have 21, but if you keep asking good questions and writing good answers, I'm sure you'll get there in no time.